# How to change the date format of ISOString?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timestamp

How can I change the output to be more readable? from this 2015-04-25T00:00:00Z to 2015-04-2 00:00:00-00:00:00

I am using this (new Date()).toISOString()

Comment: Which Javascript reference are you using? Looks more like a string operation to me than data formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Dates are very strange beast in javascript. If at all possible I would highly recommend using a date library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to handle this for you. Using moment this would be as simple as:

`var formattedDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')`

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to handle it in JavaScript. You get the Date and then the various parts. Then you concatenate them together into a variable to use as you wish.

```
var d = new Date();
var dy = d.getDate();
var dmth = d.getMonth();
var dyr = d.getFullYear();
var dFullDate = dyr+ '/' +dmth+ '/' +dy;
```